# localStorage() storing variables

Tags: javascript

My code: 
(there is 1200 lines of code and all I need is variables), I need help filling the save(); and load(); so it loads and saves all variables using localStorage (so you can access it any time on same pc). Thanks for any help.

```
var xp = 0;
var xpN = 10;
var level = 1;
var population = 4;
var populationLimit = 5;
var populationProd = 0;
var questpoints = 0.5;
var questpointsboost = 1;
var autoquest = "false";
//Resources
var gold = 11;
var food = 25;
var wood = 0;
var stone = 0;
var iron = 0;
var goldmax = 15;
var foodmax = 5;
var woodmax = 5;
var stonemax = 5;
var ironmax = 5;

var prize = 0;

var trade1 = 0;
var trade2 = 0;
var item1 = 0;
var item2 = 0;
var userAns = "";
// workers
var soldier = 12;
var randomnumber = 0;


var farmer = 0.1;
var lumberjack = 0;
var stoneminer = 0;
var ironminer = 0;

var farmercount = 0;
var maxfarmer = 4;

var lumberjackcount = 0;
var lumberjackmax = 0;

var stoneminercount = 0;
var stoneminermax = 0;

var ironminercount = 0;
var ironminermax = 0;

function save(){

}

function load(){

}
```

Comment: should I send you my paypal account?

Comment: why ? I just started javascript and I dont want paid help. You will probably take like 5$ for one bit of code that I can get for free somewhere. Or can get a book for 30$ about javascript programming. I am just exploring languages. Just playing around. NO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is lazy.

Comment: so...you don't get javascript and sarcasm...

Comment: very non-professional attitude .. sad

Answer (score 1):

You can save values like this

```
>localStorage.setItem('variable_name', 'value')
```

and then you can get that value

```
>localStorage.getItem('variable_name')
```

You can store keys in variables and then get that value from localStorage against that key

```
var playerName = 'player';
localStorage.setItem(playerName, 'John Doe');
```

and next time you can get that value

```
var player = localStorage.getItem(playerName);
```

Comment: Nooo, OP wants you to write the code instead of just a hint....... OP will downvote your answer :D

Comment: but for value I wanted to make it variable value. Not custom value. I need to be able to save the game and load it whenever. so do I just put variable name in there twice ? localStorage.setItem("food","food") ?